# How to find out and control which elements gets scrolling keyboard events?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML has scrollable elements. At any given time one of them is going to receive keyboard scrolling controls like up/down arrow, pageup/pagedown etc.

How can I find out which element is currently active in this way, and how can I make an element active in this way?

[Here's jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/acLg8047/16/).

I can click on `e1`, `e2`, `e3`, or `e4`. If I do, then arrow keys will scroll that element.

The obvious way to do this would be to call `element.focus()`. But that does nothing when called on a scrollable div, and `document.activeElement` keeps pointing to `body` not to any of them (the one that's actually active, or the one I tried to make active).

So:

- is there some other DOM thing which controls it?
- or is this functionality not exposed by browsers in any way?
- or do I need to set a bunch of `tabindex` settings to access this state through JS, even though browsers can handle active scrolling status without any `tabindex` by theselves?

Answer (score 1):

After some research and testing, I conclude that this is **not exposed** and **not directly controllable**, at least not in a way that is reliable, documented, or consistent across user agents, platforms, and assistive technologies that the user may have. Circumstantial evidence:

1. Tests suggest that the latent keyboard scroll target is browser/platform dependent. For example, in Chromium when the user clicks the body outside of one of the scrollable elements, then no element will be scrolled with the arrow keys. However in Firefox, if the user clicks the blank space below a scrollable element, then that element **will** receive the keyboard-based scrolling behaviors. (The browsers also have differing behavior, for example when the scrolling element is styled with "user-select: none".) This suggests that tactics like "track what was last clicked" will not work reliably.
2. In this [standards draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-window-interface) referenced by MDN's article on [document.scrollingElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/scrollingElement), it has this note:

> ISSUE 1:  User agents do not agree whether this uses the (coordinated)
> viewport perform a scroll or the scrolling box perform a scroll on the
> layout viewport’s scrolling box.

3. In [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets) about keyboard navigability, tabIndex and focus() are discussed, but this latent keyboardable scroll behavior is not discussed.
4. Some platforms (e.g. Linux Window Managers) may direct scrolling behavior with the mouse hover position rather than click, focus, or text selection. Assistive technologies such as browser plugins that perform voice commands or eye tracking may programmatically scroll any item without the browser's participation.

### Workarounds

1. If the goal is to stop the behavior, then calling preventDefault() on the relevant keyboard events does work. Other assistive technologies and behaviors may not be stopped, but the keys the OP asked about would be.
2. If the goal is to know what **is** being scrolled, hooking all the scrollables on the page with `e.addEventListener('scroll',...)` and inspecting their Event.target field worked in my tests of Chromium, Safari, and Firefox. (But the scrolling can't be stopped at that point, only observed, because [there is no pre-scroll event to hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981552/event-that-gets-fired-before-not-after-dom-elements-are-scrolled-in-javascrip).)
3. If the goal is to prevent scrolling, overflow:hidden does that. If the goal is to stop scrolling temporarily but not disrupt the scroll position, [this answer seems to be the consensus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3656618).

Comment: Is there a workaround if the goal is to activate an element for keyboard scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Use Event Listeners To Do So

```
function gg1(){
document.getElementById("focused").innerText = "e1"
}
function gg2(){
document.getElementById("focused").innerText = "e2"
}
document.getElementById("e1").addEventListener("scroll", gg1);
document.getElementById("e2").addEventListener("scroll",gg2);
```

This Code Is Just The Basic Version Of How You could achieve it. You can always minify it.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to answer the question? The poster wants to discover / change which element WILL receive scroll events, e.g. before they arrive. Event listeners can only react to scroll events once they're already being delivered.

Comment: @ZeroTrickPony it does a very close job. Scroll event is not just run after the user finishes scrolling, it also is present when user is lets say mid-way scrolling because the "scroll" event is still being triggered. You can try out in the Js Fiddle the above code, and it seems to work, at least as OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the focused element with `window.getSelection().focusNode`. If nothing is focused, then it seems the arrow keys affect `document.scrollingElement`. Note that some elements will "capture" the arrow key press and prevent cause scrolling. Some examples are input[type=text], textarea, select.

Once you have the focused element, traverse up the DOM tree to find the closest scrollable element. For example:

```
function getActiveScrollableElement() {
    // You probably should check if document.activeElement is a text input (or select, textarea, ...) 
    // If so, then the arrow keys won't cause scrolling

    let scrollableElement = window.getSelection().focusNode || document.scrollingElement;
    while (scrollableElement && !scrollableElement.scrollTopMax) {
        scrollableElement = scrollableElement.parentElement;
    }
    return scrollableElement;
}
```

Comment: I tested this in Chrome and Chromium and I couldn't ever observe document.scrollingElement set to anything other than body. I saw that focusNode does seem to be a good hint, but when the tree is styled with user-select: none; the focusNode value is always null regardless of this behavior. There seems to still be some latent state elsewhere regarding which scrollable element will receive these scrolling commands. The questioner (and me! :) want to know where this state can be observed.

Comment: @ZeroTrickPony interesting. On Firefox if the dom is `user-select: none` you'll find that scrolling with the arrow keys doesn't work -- except on <body> (for me this seems to be the case anyways). If you find a another way to do it in Chrome/ium please do update us!

Comment: I guess one thing you could do is bind all clicks, and record the target element.
This should give you "active" element, then go up the tree till you find something scrollable.